# D3 v3 Force Layout - gracefully add/remove nodes without refresh

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout, d3-force-directed

**Scenario:**

I started with a standard D3 v3 Force Layout 
 that I took from an example online.

I want to enhance this and my aim is:

1. When script loads call a function to initialise and render graph with some data
2. Click a button to update the graph on the page to add/remove nodes and links **gracefully** - i.e. **without a complete re-draw** with nodes 'flying' in.

An example of the type of behaviour I desire is this fantastic graph where dragging the threshold slider 'pops' links in/out without a complete re-render so it is easy to see what has been added/removed: http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/TdHgx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TdHgx

**Problem:**

- I am unsure how to achieve point number 2 above.
- I cannot update my graph with a complete redraw
- I am faily sure the answer is something to do with how I use the D3 general update pattern.

Here is an example of what I have so far:https://jsfiddle.net/samollason/uvqosxrr/3/

Code for jsfiddle:

---

**html:**

```
<body>

  <button id="update-button1">Update Data - Remove</button>
  <button id="update-button2">Update Data - Add</button>

</body>
```

**js:**

```
var width = 400,
    height = 500;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragstart", dragstart);

//Set up the force layout
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    //we call this function when we first draw graph
    var drawInit = function(graph){

    link = link.data(graph.links, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 12)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(drag);

    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();
};

    //call this function whenever we want to update the graph
var update = function(graph){

    link = link.data(graph.links, function(d) { return d.id; });

    link.exit().remove();

    link
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

    //Remove nodes not in new data set
    node.exit().remove();

    //For each datum in dataset that wasn't in old dataset append 
      circle
    node.enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 12)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(drag);

    //Update the force layout graph
    force
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .start();
};

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
    console.log("double clicked on " + d.name);
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

//data1 is used for our initial drawing
data1 = {
    "nodes": [
    {
        "id":0,
        "name": 0,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 10
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "name": 1,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 10
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name": 2,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 20
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "name": 3,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 30
    },
    {
        "id":4,
        "name": 4,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 25
    }
],
    "links": [
    {
        "source": 1, "target": 0, "value":1, "id":0
    },
    {
        "source": 1, "target": 2, "value":1, "id":1
    },
    {
        "source": 1, "target": 3, "value":1, "id":2
    },
    {
        "source": 1, "target": 4, "value":1, "id":3
    }
]

};

drawInit(data1);

//When user clicks on button update force layout graph *gracefully*
d3.select("#update-button1").on("click", function(e) {

    var data2 = {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": 0,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": 1,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": 2,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": 3,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 30
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1, "id": 0
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 1, "id": 1
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 1, "id": 2
            }
        ]
    };

        update(data2);
});

//When user clicks on button update force layout graph *gracefully*
d3.select("#update-button2").on("click", function(e) {

    //this simulates removing a node
    var data3 = {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "name": 0,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": 1,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": 2,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": 3,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 30
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": 4,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 30
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": 5,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 30
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 0, "value": 1, "id": 0
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 1, "id": 1
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 3, "value": 1, "id": 2
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 4, "value": 1, "id": 3
            },
            {
                "source": 1, "target": 5, "value": 1, "id": 4
            }
        ]
    };

    update(data3);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my question. Essentially, to achieve 'graceful' updating one must **mutate** the data initially assigned to the force layout object "nodes"/"links" properties **instead of reassigning and overwriting** them.

Here is an example I created: https://jsfiddle.net/thedev19/z3rwpcxp/27/

One could still load data from an external source that had some nodes/links added/removed and then **compare** the newly provided data with the current data assigned to the force layout "nodes" and "links" properties". Then add/remove nodes/links appropriately to **mutate** the "nodes"/"links" data initially assigned to the force layout graph in its properties.

Code for jsfiddle:

```
<body>

<p>Click and drag nodes to 'stick' them to a desired location</p>
<p>Click button to see how we can 'gracefully' update the graph <br>
    and add data without completely re-loading</p>

  <button id="update1">Update - Click to add nodes</button>
</body>
```

js:

```
//Variables to set up SVG container
var width = 400,
    height = 350;

//We initialise the force layout object here
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-400)
    .linkDistance(40)
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Create a "g" container elements and create selections to reference throughout
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");

var update = function(){

    //Create an UPDATE selection by joining data with "link" element selection
    link = link.data(graphData.links, function(d){ return d.id});

    //Access ENTER selection (hangs off UPDATE selection)
    //This represents newly added data that dont have DOM elements
    //so we create and add a "line" element for each of these data
    link
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link");

    //Access EXIT selection (hangs off UPDATE selection)
    //This represents DOM elements for which there is now no corresponding data element
    //so we remove these from DOM
    link
        .exit().remove();

    //same update pattern for nodes
    node = node.data(graphData.nodes);

    node.
    enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 12)
        .on("dblclick", dblclick)
        .call(drag);

    node.exit().remove();

    force
        .start();

};

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

function dblclick(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
}

function dragstart(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
}

function init(){

    var data1 = {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "id":0,
                "name": 0,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id":1,
                "name": 1,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 10
            },
            {
                "id":2,
                "name": 2,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 20
            },
            {
                "id":3,
                "name": 3,
                "group": 1,
                "size": 30
            }
        ],
        "links": [
            {
                "source": 0, "target": 1, "value":1, "id":0
            },
            {
                "source": 0, "target": 2, "value":1, "id":1
            },
            {
                "source": 0, "target": 3, "value":1, "id":2
            }
        ]

    };

    graphData = data1;
    drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);

    force.links(graphData.links);
    force.nodes(graphData.nodes);

    update()
}

init();

d3.select("#update1").on("click", function() {

    //randomly select a (currently existing) node that our new node will link to
    var sourceNodeId = Math.floor(Math.random() * (graphData.nodes.length-1));

    //if there are n nodes currently (before we add a new one, below) then
    //the new target node will be the (n+1)th node with an id of n (zero-indexing)
    var newNodeId = graphData.nodes.length;

    // if there are currently n links (before we add a new one, below) then
    // the new link will have an id of n (first link has an id of 0)
    var linkId = graphData.links.length;

    graphData.links.push({
        "source": sourceNodeId , "target": newNodeId, "value": 1, "id": linkId
    });

    graphData.nodes.push({
        "id": newNodeId,
        "name": newNodeId,
        "group": 1,
        "size": 30
    });

    update()

});
```

css:

```
.link {
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
    cursor: move;
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.fixed {
    fill: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to use ur code to input from another json, but unable to achieve the same result. Would u be able to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482901/d3-js-update-force-directed-graph-with-another-json-file

Comment: Hi. I cannot open the link you have provided. It may be a problem with the way you are supplying data. I suggest copying the data from your json file (if this is how you are copying it across) and placing it in the 'data1' array in the code above.

Comment: Hi again, you're right, I made a mistake in supply the data, which is to push it as an object instead of the entire json array to update. However, I encountered another incident when I tried to include node labels. Have posted the question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49528368/d3-graceful-upload-of-new-node-links-error-when-labels-are-enabled